# Signtool - how to sign a macOS file (file format not recognized)

Tags: linux, macos, ssl-certificate, sign, signtool

I am working on an app on C# and I generate the executables for both Windows and macOS, and they both run fine.

When I use the signtool to sign the windows executable, it works fine, but with the macOS file it fails.

I am probably giving the wrong arguments, but I have also not found what are the correct ones for macOS or linux.

My command:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.1\x64>.\signtool.exe sign /n company /fd sha256 /tr http://ts.ssl.com /td sha256 "C:\Users\Ler\Desktop\maxOSsign\file"
```

Returns:

```
Done Adding Additional Store

SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.

SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign: C:\Users\Ler\Desktop\maxOSsign\file
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I doubt signtool can produce a signature that is recognized on Mac OS anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows and macOS signatures are different, you can't use signtool to sign macOS applications. You have to use codesign instead.